# Неправильно строятся div JQuerry

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!
Вкратце опишу проблему
Мой скрипт запрашивает данные из базы(вопросы). Скрипт должен строить div для каждого вопроса

```js
 <script>
        $.getJSON("/questions/all",function (resp){
            $.each(resp, function(index){
                jQuery('<div class = "question">').appendTo('#info')
                $('<div class  ="qHead">').appendTo('.question');
                $('<a class  = "name">').html(this.author.name).appendTo('.qHead')
                $(".name").attr(href = "authors/"+this.author.id);
                $('<h5 class = "date">').html(this.question.dateOfCreation).appendTo('.qHead')
                $('<div class = "qBody">').appendTo(".question")
                $('<a class = "body">').html(this.question).appendTo(".qBody")
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Скрипт получает JSON

```
[{"themes":"JAVA","question":"What?","author":{"name":"mish","rating":0,"id":1},"dateOfCreation":1686145863480,"answers":[],"id":1},{"themes":"JOB","question":"Where?","author":{"name":"mish","rating":0,"id":1},"dateOfCreation":1686145863480,"answers":[],"id":2}]
```

По итогу строит такие div
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит все как вложенный цикл, но используется всего лишь один.
Прошу прощения за картинки.

Comment: Хотел сразу минусануть.. но все же спрошу) не правильно строит... а как правильно?

Comment: По типу новостной ленты на форуме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сформируйте разметку целиком, а потом добавляйте в дерево. Сейчас условный `appendTo('.class')` у вас добавляет ко всем элементам класса, а не только к текущему, который вы строите.

Внутренность цикла примерно следующая должна быть

```
let html = `<div class="question">
              <div class="qHead">
                <a class="name" href="/authors/${this.author.id}">
                  ${this.author.name}
                </a>
                <h5 class="date>${this.question.dateOfCreation}</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="qBody">
                <a class=body">${this.question}</a>
              </div>
            </div>`;
$(html).appendTo("#info");
```